# Magento2 loading admin layout and template in a new page

Tags: magento2, layout, custom-block

I can't get my head wrap around this.

I have this controller

```
namespace   Vendor\Gift\Controller\Adminhtml\Gift;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;

class Index extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
     */
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context
     */
    public function __construct(
            Context $context
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {       
        $resultPage = $this->resultFactory->create(\Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory::TYPE_PAGE);
        return  $resultPage;
    }

}
```

This layout in view/adminhtml/layout/vendor_gift_index.xml

**EDIT:**

Changed layout to  view/adminhtml/layout/gift_gift_index.xml
after this answer

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/102800/36102

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="styles"/>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
           <block class="Vendor\Gift\Block\Adminhtml\Gift\Index"  name="vendor.gift.index"  
                    template="Vendor_Gift::gift/index.phtml"  />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

And a template file in:

```
view/adminhtml/templates/gift/index.phtml
```

and a block

namespace   Vendor\Gift\Block\Adminhtml\Gift;

```
class Index extends  \Magento\Backend\Block\Template
{
    protected $_template = 'gift/index.phtml';

    public function __construct(
            \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
    ) { 
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    protected function _toHtml() {
        return $this->_template;
    }
}
```

Why is my output on the page just showing :

```
Vendor_Gift::gift/index.phtml
```

instead of the html from the template. Really stuck on this and so close... someone help, please

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your file name needs to be changed like this:

**From**

`vendor_gift_index.xml`

**To**

`gift_gift_index.xml`

Comment: ok, but how to connect t the template to the Vendor\Gift\Block\Adminhtml\Gift.php ? it actually put out something to the page, but it is what i have difined in the protected function _toHtml() function of the block, how can i connect it to the template ?

Answer (score 2):

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/102800/36102

combined with remove

```
protected function _toHtml() {
    return $this->_template;
}
```

I have no idea why this worked, but it actually passes variables from the Block to the template and parses the html content of the template, which is awesome :)