# Magento 2 ui component form without database table

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, uicomponent, adminform, ui-form

I want to add a UI component form in the admin panel. It is just sending email, no need of database storage. I want to redirect to my form when I click my menu "Send Coupon". 
I have tried the below UI component XML. But it shows "Not registered handle coupon_email_data_source" error

```
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">coupon_email.coupon_email_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">coupon_email.coupon_email_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true"> Information</item>
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">data</item>
            <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">coupon_email</item>
        </item>
        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">templates/form/collapsible</item>
    </argument>
    <dataSource name="coupon_email_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">coupon_email_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
        </argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>
    <fieldset name="base_fieldset">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true"> Details</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <field name="id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Coupon</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>        
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: you should use a simple phtml template instead of ui-component

Comment: We need this in our extension. Is it the right way?

Comment: if you just want a simple form without any database values, you can call phtml template with form, it would be much easier

Comment: Please share the sample code if you can

Comment: you can do it  the same way as we call template in frontend, you can check [this reference](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/102789/magento2-loading-admin-layout-and-template-in-a-new-page)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For this, Your Data Provider should be like

```
<dataSource name="coupon_email_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Namespace\ModuleName\Model\DataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">coupon_email_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
        </argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
</dataSource>
```

> Namespace\ModuleName\Model\DataProvider

And create Your DataProvider.php In Model Directory like Model/DataProvider.php

```
namespace Namespace\ModuleName\Model;


class DataProvider extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider
{
    /**
     * Get data
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getData()
    {
        return [];
    }

}
```

You will see the form then.

Comment: Additionally, You may need to implement the method addFilter(). I got an error `Call to a member function addFieldToFilter() on null` when only getData() alone is used.